# PHP and XSD Regular expression for currency and location names

Tags: regex, validation, preg-match, xsd-validation

I am trying to find a suitable regular expression that allows number, digits, spaces and other characters that can be used in names such as . ' -_. I need to implement an expression as a PHP preg_match and an XSD pattern. Currently I have the following for PHP

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 '-.]
```

Which allows the characters I want (unless there are any other special characters you could kindly recommend I use). The issue with this is that it allows special characters to be used one after the other, allowing values such as .-- . I need it so that this can't happen, only allowing a special character if a letter or digit comes before it.

I would also like the equivalent for an XSD pattern but everything I have tried so far has been inadequate. I am currently using

```
[\w\d '-.']*[\w\d][\w\d '-.]*
```

In addition, the length must be between 3-50 (which works in all cases currently).

Any guidance would be fantastic as I have searched high and low for an answer.

Valid names could be:

- Netherlands Antillean guilde
- Timor-Leste
- Cote d'Ivoire

Including letters with accents.

Invalid names could be:

- Tes''t
- Test (space before)
- _test (special character before
- -'.
- ...

Comment: Some valid examples would be helpful.

Comment: Of course, my apologies,  I'll add some in now.

Comment: Are you trying to validate official names or usernames ? Because you mentioned digits to be added too.

Comment: Official names, not for username. They should be valid against ISO 4217 countries and currencies. I just went through the document I'm using and I must've removed all the ones that had numbers in so in actual fact they could be removed. But names such as U.S. or d'Ivoire etc should be allowed.